# Complex Analysis: Laurent Series Expansion in region for 22 C.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I have solved the others but I am really struggling on 22c. I need it to converge for $|z|>2$. This is the part I am really struggling with. I am trying to get both fractions into a geometric series with $1/(1-(1/(z/2))$ so that it converges for $1/(z/2)<1$; which becomes, ($z>2$). I however cannot manipulate either series into this form that I am looking for. I have tried many times. I have also tried combining both fractions into one fraction over $z^2-1$, but am not getting anywhere. Any pointers, or tips so that I can get it to converge for $|z|>2$ by manipulating the fractions (just simply cannot get in right form). Thank you.Image url is attached.

[Laurent Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2PC9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}&=\frac{2}{z^2}\left(\frac{1}{1-1/z^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^{2n}}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{z^{2n}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain how you derived the first step, the part where 1/(2z^2) * 1/(1-(1/z^2)).  That would be helpful, trying to understand process.

Comment: You're welcome and sure.  Note that $\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z+1}=\frac{2}{z^2-1}$.  There was a typo - Good catch!

Comment: Yes, I was just doing that on scratch paper.  But how does 2/(z^2-1) =1/(2z^2) * (1/(1-(1/z^2))? Thanks.

Comment: Ahh I see.  Thank you again.

Comment: Factor out $z^2$ from $z^2-1$ to arrive at $z^2(1-1/z^2)$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: How do I know/verify that the series converges for 2<|z|<infinity?

Comment: The series converges for $|z|>1$.  So, it also converges for $|z|>2$.

Comment: Last question, sorry.

Comment: I upvoted but my reputation isn't high enough.  If the series converges for |z|>1, how do I necessarily know that it converges for |z|>2.

Comment: Because we have $1<2$.

Comment: Okay, I did that, thanks.

Comment: And you're most welcome.  Let me know if you have other questions on MSE that I can help you answer.

Comment: There is actually one more Laurent Series question.  I will post a new thread.